# PhotoSwipe JS gallery, remove specific event handler

Tags: javascript

In [PhotoSwipe](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/blob/master/src/photoswipe.class.js) JavaScript image gallery is there any way to remove a specific event handler? I found you can remove ALL but I found no way to remove one by name.

Answer (score 0):

try this one 
https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/issues/243